# In Python, how do I refer to an XML tag that contains a hyphen

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to use BeautifulSoup to parse an XML file.  One of the elements has a hyphen in it:  distribution-code

How do I access it?  I've tried:

```
soup.distribution-code
soup."distribution-code" (tried single quotes too)
soup.[distribution-code]
```

but none of these work.

Comment: Did you try `soup['distribution-code']`?

Comment: I think you really need [this](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Comment: That gave me this error: 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#15>", line 1, in <module>
    soup['distribution-code']
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4/element.py", line 834, in __getitem'

Comment: I didn't see an answer to my hyphen question in the documentation.  I've got it working for other elements without the hyphen

Comment: Did you try use `soup.find()` or `soup.find_all()`?

Comment: OK, soup.find() worked. - Thanks.  (by the way, how do you get the code highlighted in gray like that?)

Comment: Easy, use something like `\`code\``. See [the help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access non-hyphenated elements by attribute reference using regular Python syntax, i.e. *`obj.name`*, however, `-` is not a valid character when using that syntax (Python treats it as the "minus" operator), hence you can not access such elements by that method.

Instead, use `soup.find()` or `soup.find_all()`:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('<thing><id>1234</id><distribution-code>555444333</distribution-code></thing>')
>>> soup.thing
<thing><id>1234</id><distribution-code>555444333</distribution-code></thing>
>>> soup.id
<id>1234</id>
>>> soup.distribution-code
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'code' is not defined
>>> soup.find('distribution-code')
<distribution-code>555444333</distribution-code>
```

Or, as pointed out in [chepner's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33250363/in-python-how-do-i-refer-to-an-xml-tag-that-contains-a-hyphen#comment54302847_33250485), you can use `getattr()` and `setattr()` to get and set attributes that contain hyphens. I think that `soup.find()` is the more common method for accessing those elements.

Comment: You can using `getattr(soup, 'distribution-code')`.

Comment: @chepner: yes, very good point. By "attribute reference" I meant normal Python syntax (_`obj.name`_), not via `getattr()`. I have updated my answer to clarify and to include your suggestion.